# Mongoose: Datos del Schema desaparecen al relacionarlo con Model obteniendo un documento vacío

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, model, schema

En primer lugar gracias por entrar a la pregunta.

Estoy enfrentandome a un *issue* desde hace unos días que no consigo remediar.

Mi problema es que obtengo unos datos, los cuales relaciono a un Schema sin problemas, pero al vincularlo con el Model, los datos desaparecen del documento generado.

El error en concreto aparece en este fragmento de código:

```
switch(searchdata){
    case 'apis':
        ModelDB = getModel('apis', ApiSchema, conn);
        break;
    case 'apps':
        ModelDB = getModel('apps', AppSchema, conn);
        break;
    case 'roles':
        ModelDB = getModel('roles', RoleSchema, conn);
        break;
    case 'pi-scopes':
        ModelDB = getModel('scopes', ScopeSchema, conn);
        break;
    case 'purposes':
        ModelDB = getModel('purposes', PurposeSchema, conn);
        break;
}
console.log(insertData, ModelDB);
let newData = new ModelDB(insertData);
console.log(newData);
```

Los console log que aparecen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A pesar de que los datos los recibe a través de la variable insertData podemos ver como a la hora de generar el documento con el model los datos desaparecen en la variable newData. Viendo que si genera el identificador del documento _id, y también añade la key del Schema 'scopes', pero el resto de keys y los datos respectivos de todos los campos aparecen vacíos.

Lo extraño es que el switch con la función getModel funciona a la perfección en todos los casos salvo cuando es el case 'apis'.

Os dejo aquí mi ApiSchema:

```
const ScopeSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    guards_personal_information: Boolean
}, { _id: false });

const ApiSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    version: Number,
    title: String,
    description: String,   
    scopes: [ScopeSchema],
    contact: {
        name: String
    },
    swagger: {
        host: String,
        securityDefinitions: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        paths: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        basePath: String,
        info: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        schemes: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        produces: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        definitions: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        swagger: String,
        consumes: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        parameters: Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
    verify_identifiers: Boolean,
    tags: Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

Y os añado tambien la función getModel (la cual funciona correctamente salvo en el caso concreto 'api' por lo tanto dudo que esté aquí el error):

```
const createModel = (nombre: string, schema: Schema, conn: Connection) => {
  const modelo = conn.model(nombre, schema);
  return modelo;
}

const getModel = (nombre: string, schema: Schema, conn: Connection) => {
  let model;
  if(conn.modelNames().includes(nombre)){
    model = conn.model(nombre);
  }
  else {
    model = createModel(nombre, schema, conn);
  }
  return model;
}
```

Desconozco cual puede ser la razón para que los datos no sean vinculados al documento final.

¿Alguno os habéis enfrentado alguna vez a un *issue* similar?

¿Sois capaces de detectar el error que estoy cometiendo?

Si necesitáis algún tipo de información extra añadirlo en los comentarios y edito la pregunta con lo que necesitéis.

Muchas gracias de antemano por molestarte en leer hasta aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Analizando el código que muestras y viendo la imagen aportada, el error es que la variable `insertData` es un `Array`, y lo que espera el constructor de `ModelDB` no es un `Array` sino un documento (un Objeto de JS).

Según la documentación de la [Clase Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model), la misma recibe como argumento un parámetro de tipo Objeto que contiene la información que contendrá el documento a ser instanciado.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una forma en que podrías hacer el llamado para instanciar correctamente el documento sería la siguiente:

```js
let newData = new ModelDB(insertData[0]);
```

Eso pasará el primer elemento del `Array` al constructor del modelo.

Lo ideal es que la variable `insertData` sea del tipo correcto. Si siempre obtienes un tipo `Array` de 1 sólo elemento en dicha variable podrías hacer lo siguente:

```js
let [ newDoc ] = insertData;
let newData = new ModelDB(newDoc);
```

Por último, si recibes más de 1 elemento en el `Array` de `insertData`, podrías tranquilamente usar el método [`insertMany()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) del Modelo. Claro, siempre que desees insertar todos los documentos del `Array` y todos sean documentos pertenecientes al mismo modelo.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: En efecto añadiendo let [ newDoc ] = insertData; me funcionó perfecto (desconocía esta sintaxis) >>> Como siempre mil gracias Mauricio =)

Comment: Siempre cabe la posibilidad de que `newDoc` sea `undefined` ante ese caso, poner un condicional para evitar insertar un documento sin datos sería lo correcto: `if( newDoc !== undefined ) { let newData = new Model(newDoc) }`. Lo podrías tener en cuenta. Saludos

Comment: hmm es extraño lo que me dices, siempre me devuelve mongoose un documento (vacío en el caso de q no exista)